# Read Status Bar Notification as strings

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I need to fetch the status bar notification,ie i need to get the text of the status bar notification as  strings and show in a listview (every application).Is it possible from ICS, any idea please.

Comment: you may want to check this: http://gmariotti.blogspot.com.tr/2013/11/notificationlistenerservice-and-kitkat.html

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to new notfications using AccessibilityService. Take a look at example: http://pankajchunchun.wordpress.com/2013/07/09/capture-toast-or-notification-using-accessibility-service/

There is a one disadvantage of this solution - you have to turn on your service in device settings, before it will be able to listen to notifications.

Another way is using NotificationListenerService API, but it's available from Android 4.3:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService